# como verificar uma string no if

Tags: c

Tenho o código:
Qual motivo de ele não estar dando positivo para o if?

```
{
    char placa[9] = "G" "A" "E" "-" "0" "2" "4" "4";
    char cor[15] = "branco";
    int ano = 2001;

    printf("A placa: %s\n", placa);
    printf("A cor: %s\n", cor);
    printf("O ano: %d\n", ano);

    if(cor == "branco")
    {
        printf("voce tem um carro branco \n");
    }
    else 
    { 
        printf("voce nao tem um carro branco \n");
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**cor** é um ponteiro para um array de **chars** então quando você faz a comparação

```
cor == "branco"
```

você está comparando o valor de ponteiros e não as palavras, para comparar as palavras você pode usar a função [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) (existem varias formas de fazer essa comparação, como por exemplo criar sua própria função ou usar uma de uma biblioteca que você esteja usando).